# MSVC++ 2008 issue with linker and dll

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll, linker

I'm writing some dll which use xmlrpc-c project (http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/). I downloaded and compiled xmlrpc-c using MSVC++2008. With settings:

[image: xmlrpc-c building settings]

Now I'm trying to build my dll and link it with xmlrpc-c. I'm using settings:
[image: dll building settings]

I'm getting linker errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: [...], Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Linking...
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in xmlrpccppD.lib(value.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in xmlrpccppD.lib(value.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in xmlrpccppD.lib(value.obj)
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static unsigned int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::length(char const *)" (?length@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAIPBD@Z) already defined in xmlrpccppD.lib(value.obj)
LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __malloc_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __free_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encoded_null already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __decode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(strftime.obj) : error LNK2005: _strftime already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: ___CppXcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
LIBCMTD.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(atox.obj) : error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(getenv.obj) : error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj) : error LNK2005: __strtoui64 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
LIBCMTD.lib(strnicmp.obj) : error LNK2005: __strnicmp already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
   Creating library [...].lib and object [...].exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
[...].dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Build log was saved at "[...]\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
[...] - 34 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I was trying to add linker options:

```
/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMTD
```

But it also give strange restults.

I suspect that diffrent runtime libraries cause issue (MT debug and MT DLL debug).

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Runtime libraries are different: Multi-threaded Debug DLL vs Multi-threaded Debug.
They should be the same.

Comment: Yea, it works now. I didn't suspect that I can set Multi-threaded Debug DLL for xmlrpc-c.